# Bean method that return Future in Apache Camle route configuration

Tags: java, apache-camel, future

Hi, I'm start working with Apache Camel and I wonder if it possible to use camel like this:

Some service (bean) :

```java
public class SomeService {
    public Future<Data> someMethod() {
        //Do async job
    }
}
```

RouteBuilder pseudo configuration:

```java
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    SomeService someService; //injected instance

    public void configure() {
        from("source.route")
            .bean(someService, "someMethod")
            .to("destination.route.after.job.started")
            .afterTo("destination.route.after.job.finished") //afterTo is a concept
        .end()
    }
}
```

So `destination.route.after.job.started` will reach immediately after `someMethod` returned.
And `destination.route.after.job.finished` will reach after async job finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncProcessor](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/AsyncProcessor.html) as describe in [cookbook](http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html). Usage be like this:

```
from("file:data/in").process(new MyValidator()).threads(20)
.process(new MyTransformation()).to("jpa:PurchaseOrder");
```

For more details go through cookbook and then ask more detailed question if you will have them.